# В определённое время отправлять, каждый день, выполнять какое-то действие

Tags: javascript, node.js, дата

подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать, такую задачу. Каждый день, в определённое время, например 13:55, нужно, сделать вызвать какую-то функцию(callback).

Вот мои наработки:

главный метод startIninityMonitoring()

```
class DateTimer {
  constructor() {
    this.interval = null;
    this.stop = true;
  }

  async startIninityMonitoring(options, callback) {
    this.stop = false;
    let res = await this.start(options, callback);
    if(!this.stop){
      setTimeout(this.startIninityMonitoring(options, callback), 60*1000);
    }
  }

  async start(options, callback) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.interval = setInterval(() => {
        let dateNow = new Date();
        let dateNowOptions = {
          hours: dateNow.getHours(),
          minutes: dateNow.getMinutes(),
        };

        if (
          dateNowOptions.hours == options.hours &&
          dateNowOptions.minutes == options.minutes
        ) {
          callback();
          resolve(true);
          clearInterval(this.interval);
        }
      }, 10 * 1000);
    });
  }

  stop() {
    this.stop = true;

  }
}
module.exports = DateTimer;
```

Comment: Nodejs - cron. Вот пара ссылок: [CRON](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron) , [NODE-CRON](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron) , позволяет запускать скрипт через определённое или в установленное время.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для ноды давно придуман пакет [cron npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron)(есть аналоги, но я обычно этот использую), вполне просто настраивается и не нужно велосипед изобретать

Answer (score -2):

Ты ведь понимаешь что это работать будет только если открыт твой сайт?

По теме, Я бы реализовал так. Записывай в localStorage последнюю дату выполнения функции, и сравнивай с той которую ты получаешь сейчас, если дата больше на день или больше и текущее время тебе подходит то выполняешь. Функцию которая проверяет дату и время вызываешь при загрузке приложения и по таймауту.

Но не даю гарантий что это реально правильный подход решения твоей задачи.

Comment: Я пишу приложение на node js. Я пишу бота для вк, он работает на хостинге. В любом случае спасибо за ответ. Но это не совсем, то что мне нужно.